# Excel, WorkSheet_Change gives Sub or Function not defined

Tags: excel, vba, ms-office

I'm trying to create a bit of code that resets a cell when another cell changes.  There are three drop down cells and each cell is dependent on the cell before it (B3 is dependent on B2 and B4 is dependent on B3 and B2).

So, if someone sets B4, then changes B2, there would be in invalid combination.  So, if the cell value above is changed, it will force the cell below to default value (If B4 can only be value 3 when B1 is Value 2, then if B1 is changed to Value 1, B4 is forced into Value 1)

The code I am using now is this:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Target.Worksheet.Range("B2")) Is Nothing Then
    If Sheet("Talent Sheet").Range("B2") = Human Then
        Sheet("Talent Sheet").Range("B3") = Warrior
        Sheet("Talent Sheet").Range("B4") = "Human Noble"
    Else
        If Sheet("Talent Sheet").Range("B2") = Elf Then
            Sheet("Talent Sheet").Range("B3") = Warrior
            Sheet("Talent Sheet").Range("B4") = "City Elf"
        Else
            If Sheet("Talent Sheet").Range("B2") = Dwarf Then
                Sheet("Talent Sheet").Range("B3") = Warrior
                Sheet("Talent Sheet").Range("B4") = "Dwarf Commoner"
            End If
        End If
    End If
```

This would, when B2 changes, force B3 and B4 to their defaults, but I get a Compile Error "Sub or Function is not defined"

I honestly have no idea what is causing this.  M$ help says it's because the sub procedure is spelled wrong, but I've copied some of this code and checked it against a lot of sources.

Comment: Unless Human, Warrior, etc. are variables, they should be in quotes.

Comment: Agreed - You need to put those in quotes.

Answer (score 9):

You are using `Sheet` instead of `Sheets`.

By using `Sheet` the editor thinks you are looking for a new function called `Sheet` and cannot find it defined anywhere (because it is not a VBA defined function), so it gives that error.

Additionally, you are likely going to want to use `"` around `human`, `Dwarf`, etc, unless those are defined somewhere.

Finally, I would **strongly** recommend using `Option Explicit` at the top of each of your modules as this will help prevent many errors (such as the `Human` `Dwarf` text not being in `"`) of this sort.

Comment: Thank you very much.  The "Sheets" thing was a silly mistake on my part, and I took note and added quotes to all the values.  Also, "Option Explicit" is on that module, but I'll add it to all as I go through.

Answer (score 2):

Three things besides what enderland has covered.

1. You do not need the sheet name. It is understood that the code is to be run on current sheet
2. Whenever you are working with `Worksheet_Change` event. Always switch Off events if you are writing data to the cell. This is required so that the code doesn't go into a possible endless loop
3. Whenever you are switching off events, use error handling else if you get an error, the code will not run the next time.

Here is an example

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    On Error GoTo Whoa

    Application.EnableEvents = False

    '
    '~~> Rest of the code
    '

LetsContinue:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Exit Sub
Whoa:
    MsgBox Err.Description
    Resume LetsContinue
End Sub
```

Comment: I kind of thought it'd go in a loop but figured maybe Excel would stop looping code automatically, but I'll add it in just in case.  Thank you.